# how to construct this mongoose shema?

Tags: mongoose, database, nosql

here is what i want

```
var ImgSchema = new Schema({
      thum_src:String,
      Img_name:String,
      Img_path:String,
 })

var ProductSchema = new Schema({
      owner_id:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'User'},
      shop_id:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Shop'},
      product_name:String,
      product_category:String,
      product_price:Number,
      product_thum:String,

      product_img:[ImgSchema ],

      add_date:{type:Date,default:Date.now()}
})
```

is it possible to define product_img like what i did , well that is what i want,

and how to save data into product_img field,

i use

```
       <input  name='thum_src' value="thum_src">
       <input name='img_name' value="img_name">
       <input name='img_path' value="img_path">
```

it wont work the product_img field is an empty array。

i did a ajax post to post the data , and on server side this is what i did

```
 image = mongoose.model('image')
 exports.add = function(req, res){
// console.log(req.body)
    image = {
           thum_src:req.body.thum_src,
           img_name:req.body.img_name,
           img_path:req.body.img_path,
         }
  var data = new Product({
           owner_id:req.user.id,
           shop_id:req.user.shop_id,
           product_name:req.body.product_name,
           product_category:req.body.product_category,
           product_price:req.body.product_price,
           product_thum:req.body.product_thum,
})

data.product_img.push(image);
Product.create(data,function(err,products){
    if(err) console.log(err)
    // console.log(data);
    res.send(products);
})
};
```

Comment: Schema definition should work as is.  You'll need to post your code that populates `product_img` if you want help figuring out why that isn't working.

Comment: What does `data` look like right before the `Product.create` call?

Comment: well i finally make it work, check out the edit, but there is another problem, since user can upload multi images, i need to post multi image data, so i dont think this appended <input  name='thum_src' value="thum_src">
       <input name='img_name' value="img_name">
       <input name='img_path' value="img_path"> will work ,any idea how to make it work?